# Which countries/states allow or prohibit non-compete clauses in agreements?

Tags: job-change, contracts

Some countries/states allow companies to have a [non-compete clause / covenant not to compete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-compete_clause) in their contract which *prohibits employees from joining another company in same field for a period (for example, 3 years) after the employee leaves current company*. (usually this kind contract does not provide any extra reward for unemployed state by the contract)

Which countries/states (in case of U.S.) legally allow (or prohibit) this kind of contract?

Comment: Hi Eonil and welcome to the Workplace. I've edited your question to include the technical term you describe, a "non compete clause". Please feel free to edit it back if you were thinking of something else.

Comment: @MattGiltaji Thanks for editing. I think the term is precisely what I wanted to say. Also I hope my question to be proper on this site.

Comment: @MattGiltaji Oh actually the Wikipedia link seems  answering to my question. Please consider adding your wikipedia link as an answer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal issues.  This should really be answered by a lawyer not on this site.

Comment: @JustinCave I agree on legality part and am aware of that. But I am not sure whether this is off-topic or not. If you think so, please vote (or delete) to close.

Comment: I am voting to close because the question is too broad, and our site is not a research service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with most legalish questions, your best bet to determine the legality of a specific employment contract is to talk to an employment lawyer.

With that said, as documented on wikipedia, [non-compete clauses / covenants not to compete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-compete_clause) are allowed in most states of the US, but are restricted from being too broad and/or lasting too long in:

- Virginia
- Florida
- California
- Massachusetts
- Washington
- Texas

Wikipedia also says that Canada and Europe generally enforce these types of contracts if they are *reasonable*, meaning that they protect a *legitimate business interest*, and are limited in *time frame*, *business scope*, and *geographical scope*.

### tl;dr

[Non-compete clauses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-compete_clause) are allowed in most states and countries, but the terms of the contract have to be *reasonable*. Check with a lawyer for what *reasonable* means in your specific circumstance and location.

Comment: In general, in Europe the employee must get something for it, e.g. a one-time money compensation or a small rent for the duration of the non-compete clause, otherwise the clause is illegal.

Comment: In addition, EU citizens living in a different EU country are protected by EU regulations, not by possibly weaker protections of their own country or the country they are living in. It would be very hard to prevent a EU citizen from working in a different EU country.